# Unity to Structure Map

Tags: c#, structuremap, unity-container, ioc-container

I am trying out the code from this post on [Event Driven Architecture](http://elegantcode.com/2010/01/06/event-driven-architecture-publishing-events-using-an-ioc-container/) (very interesting by the way). His IOC container is Unity though and I would like to do this using Structure map.

His code is:

```
public class EventSubscriptions : ISubscriptionService
{
   public static void Add<T>()
   {
       var consumerType = typeof(T);

       consumerType.GetInterfaces()
                   .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
                   .Where(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IConsumer<>))
                   .ToList()
                   .ForEach(x => IoC.Container.RegisterType(x, 
                                                            consumerType, 
                                                            consumerType.FullName));
   }

   public IEnumerable<IConsumer<T>> GetSubscriptions<T>()
   {
       var consumers =  IoC.Container.ResolveAll(typeof(IConsumer<T>));
       return consumers.Cast<IConsumer<T>>();
   }
}
```

I have the following which does not seem to be working:

```
public class SubscriptionService : ISubscriptionService
{
    public static void Add<T>()
    {
        var consumerType = typeof(T);

        consumerType.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
            .Where(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IConsumer<>))
            .ToList().ForEach(x => ObjectFactory.Inject(consumerType, x));                                  
    }

    public IEnumerable<IConsumer<T>> GetSubscriptions<T>()
    {
        var consumers = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(typeof(IConsumer<T>));
        return consumers.Cast<IConsumer<T>>();
    }
}
```

I am obviously not too familiar with Structure Map. Some links or explanation on what I am doing wrong would be really appreciated.

**Update:**

From Henning's answer, I ended up with -

```
public class SubscriptionService : ISubscriptionService
{
    public IEnumerable<IConsumer<T>> GetSubscriptions<T>()
    {
        var consumers = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(typeof(IConsumer<T>));
        return consumers.Cast<IConsumer<T>>();
    }
}
```

And then in my bootstrapping class that is called on application startup I have:

```
public static void ConfigureStuctureMap()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {       
                x.Scan(y =>
                {
                    y.Assembly("Domain");           
                    y.Assembly("Website");
                    y.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IConsumer<>));
                    y.WithDefaultConventions();
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not a structuremap expert, I do believe you can do it in another way.

Structuremap has the ability to scan any given assembly for a given interface and automatically register all the implementations. We do that in my current project and it works really great.

I don't remember the exact code we use, but you can check out the documentation for assembly scanning

http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm

Answer (score 0):

Build custom TypeScanner class that implement ITypeScanner interface.

```
public class EventSubConventionScanner : ITypeScanner
{
    public void Process(Type type, PluginGraph graph)
    {
        Type interfaceType = type.FindInterfaceThatCloses(typeof(IConsumer<>));

        if (interfaceType != null)
        {
            graph.AddType(interfaceType, type);
        }
    }
}
```

After, in registry or initialize routine write:

```
 Scan(x =>
        {
            x.With<EventSubConventionScanner>();
        });
```